# XHTML/JS OnClick radio button need navigate to another page based on option value in select

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using a select options dropdown and a couple of radio button inputs in my xhtml pages. I have already written code under select element so that when the user chooses an option from the select element, the onchange attrribute in it will take it to another page as displayed in options value.

However, I need a similar behaviour with radio button input too. So, when a user clicks any button, I need it to get the value from the already selected option and navigate to that page.

How can I achieve this?

```
<select id="color" onchange="location = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value+'?view=calView';">
    <option value="page1.htm">Page1</option>
    <option value="page2.htm">page2</option>
    <option value="page3.htm">Page3</option>
</select>
<input id="cal" name="view_opt" value="calView" type="radio" />
<label for="cal">Calendar View</label>
<input id="list" name="view_opt" value="listView" type="radio" />
<label for="list">List View</label>
```

Comment: What is your jQuery/js code so far?

Comment: Hi, the code is already there. I have written javascript within onchange attribute in select element which navigates the user to the page as mentioned in the option value. I require the same but within onclick or onchnage attribute of input radiobutton type element where when selected, it navigates to the page as in the value of already selected option in select element. Does it make any sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes that should work fine or to make code more generalize pass this in the onclick function and handle all tour assignments in the single function

Comment: Thanks Shashi. onclick="location = document.getElementById('color').value" worked.